# Perform conditional calculations in a R data frame

Tags: r

I have data in a dataframe in R like this:

### Value   | Metric

10      | KG
5       | lbs       etc.

I want to create a new column (weight) where I can calculate a converted weight based on the Metric  - something like if Metric = "Kg" then Value * 1, if Metric = "lbs" then Value * 2.20462

I also have another use case I want to do a similar conditional calculation but based on continuous values i.e. if x >= 2 then "Classification" elseif x >= 1 then "Classification 2" else "Other

Any ideas that might work for both in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(converted_wt = case_when(Metric == 'lbs' ~ Value * 2.20462, TRUE ~ Value))
  Value Metric converted_wt
1    10     KG      10.0000
2     5    lbs      11.0231
```

If you have other units apart from "KG" and "lbs" you need to include those in `case_when` condition accordingly.

Comment: I was hoping it would - it looked right but I got this error: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `C_Weight`.
x non-numeric argument to binary operator
i Input `C_Weight` is `case_when(Metric == "lbs" ~ Value * 2.20462, TRUE ~ Value)`.

Comment: @MorneLippiatt,  Can you check the datatype of `Value` column? Is it numeric?

Comment: It is not... how can I change it?  I tried as.numeric but get another error saying it cannot be coerced to double.

Comment: I think I got it!  Used mutate(Value = as.numeric(DF$Value)) and that seemed to have worked.  Thanks!